# Python selenium click on a button multiples times

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to click on an "Add" button located in diffents page places, and I need to click on it many times as I have a list containing numbers which is equal to numbers of clicking the "Add" button. I've enumerate a that return index and numbers like:

```
1: 10
2: 9
3: 9
4: 3
5: 4
```

The index belongs to the location of the "Add" button and the numbers corresponds to the numbers of time I want to click on the "Add" button foreach button location.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

Here's the code sample

```
for location, add in enumerate(get_click_number_by_location):
        set_click_by_location[location] = add
        for n_location in set_click_by_location.keys():  
            add_click = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f"//div[@id='part-{n_location}/accordeon']//div[contains(@class,'btn--children')][normalize-space()='Add']")
            add_click_by_location = self.driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click()', add_click)
            for add in set_click_by_location.values():
                add_click_by_location
```

Comment: Please provide the relevant bit of code so that we can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finnaly managed to get a solution, if it could help someone, here's the code:

```
        for location, add in enumerate(get_click_number_by_location):
            n_location = location
            add_click = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f"//div[@id='part-{n_location}/accordeon']//div[contains(@class,'btn--children')][normalize-space()='Add']")
            for add_item in range(add - 1):
                self.driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click()', add_click)
```